# Tomcat NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

After editing my code to work with JNI, I got a `NoClassDefFoundError` on my JSP. I can't seem to understand why when I've all my `.java and .class` in the `WEB-INF/classes/matrixcalculator` path. The `.h, .c and .so` are in `WEB-INF/classes/` right next to the `matrixcalculator` folder. This is the code error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator
org.apache.jsp.adminOnly_jsp._jspService(adminOnly_jsp.java:69)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
org.apache.jsp.requestPermission_jsp._jspService(requestPermission_jsp.java:87)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

It was working before but after just adding a native function, the loadLibrary and the other files, I get this error. I tried changing the files to the same folders in `WEB-INF/classes/matrixcalculator` and still can't get out of the error. I believe it has something to do with exporting the path to where the MatrixCalculator.class is but I really can't understand to where and why. Unless Ive to put his files in a common folder for Tomcat but I could be wrong. Also I'm calling the JSP directly, not using the Tomcat manager

I added `language = "java"` and I got an error in the java bean:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /adminOnly.jsp at line 8
```

5: --%>
6: 
7: <%@page language = "java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
8: 
9: 
10: 
11:

This is the static block:

```
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("methodsViaC");
}
```

NEW ERROR after adding try/catch(Exception e):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no methodsViaC in java.library.path
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator.<clinit>(MatrixCalculator.java:77)
org.apache.jsp.adminOnly_jsp._jspService(adminOnly_jsp.java:69)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
org.apache.jsp.requestPermission_jsp._jspService(requestPermission_jsp.java:87)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

But if I refresh the page, I get the first error posted.

Comment: Do you have static block of initialisation in class MatrixCalculator?

Comment: Yes I do, I will post the static block right now! EDIT: Static block is in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that class can not been initialised, but it doesn't mean that it can't be found. So, my suggestion is to check static variables and block of static initialisation in matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator class. Looks like uncaught exception is thrown in static blocks.

Comment: So inside of the static declaration, I add the try/catch method? Using catch(Exception e)?

Comment: You can try to do this for debug proposes and to see if exception is thrown there and what kind of exception. Just write to log in catch statement. However, i think that you need to fix initialisation of class.

Comment: In my opinion you will receive UnsatisfiedLinkError. Let's check it

Comment: Indeed I got the error you said. Posted the info in the question!

Comment: Ok. looks like methodsViaC is not in your java.library.path.

Comment: You can find where to set java.library.path here http://www.coderanch.com/t/377174/java/java/java-library-path

Comment: I googled what you said and I think it could be a permission issue. Or perhaps the location of the libmethodsViaC.so 

The file is in the Web-Inf/classes directory. Is this the right place?

Comment: I would say that you need to specify it. You can leave it there. However you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH or
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=path_to_lib" if you are using linux

Comment: Also you can use a full path to your library in System.loadLibrary. However it's not the best idea

Comment: When you say path_to_lib you mean the path to where the libmethodsViaC.so is located at, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71092/discussion-between-yana-mikhaylenko-and-silvestrini).